# Passing of variable arguments in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing, optional-parameters, crt

Does anybody know how variable arguments are passed in classic C? I did some debugging today and most regular arguments are passed via stack. However it seems that this does not apply for variable arguments. Are those parameters stored somewhere else like constant strings?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very often passed on the stack. What you are looking for is ABI specifications for the platform you are using.

For the AMD64 platform, have a look for example [here](http://www.ucw.cz/~hubicka/papers/abi/node13.html#SECTION00656000000000000000).

Comment: Thats what I expected too. But I encountered a situation where I could not locate the variable arguments in the memory window of Visual Studio... Do have any documentation on parameter passing in C?

Comment: @Florian Greinacher, this is strange. I don't know what to say further, except find ABI docs for Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help finding an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the platform.  `/usr/include/stdarg.h` is the place to start looking for details.

Comment: On Unix, yes. On other platforms, `stdarg.h` may be elsewhere. +1, though.

Comment: While technically true, it is also true that you would have a hard time finding many platforms where they are NOT passed on the stack.

Comment: @Amigable: I vaguely recall SPARC doing some interesting things with the register window for varargs, but it's been a while and I don't have access to one any more.

Comment: But Win32 is not this special, is it :)

Comment: @Florian: see the previous comment, which suggests that some things are passed in registers on x86-64.  x86 will be all stack, though:  it doesn't have enough registers to even *consider* using them for argument passing.

Answer (score 1):

You meant [Variable-Length Argument Lists](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know how to use them. My question is how they are passed to the callee.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun trick

```
void func(type* values) {
    while(*values) {
        x = *values++;
        /* do whatever with x */
    }
}

func((type[]){val1,val2,val3,val4,0});
```