# How do I stop printf producing different values based on ordering?

Tags: c, printf

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(
            " %f, %u, %x,\n", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 1.000000, 1072693248, 0,

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(
            " %x, %f, %u,\n", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:  3ff00000, 0.000000, 0

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(
            " %x, %u, %f,\n", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:  3ff00000, 0, 1.000000

Is this just an issue with the number of bytes that %u and %x consume, and how do I get the values to become consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing arguments whose type does not match the corresponding component of the format string will lead to undefined results, as you've noticed. In particular, `"%x"` and `"%u"` both expect values of type (unsigned) `int`. Passing a `float` (which will often actually be represented as a `double` or `long double` depending on the ABI) is semantically incorrect.

Your compiler should be warning you about this - if not, make sure you've got all warnings enabled (`-Wall` for GCC).

If you want 1.0f as an integer, just cast:

```
printf(" %x, %u, %f\n", (unsigned)1.0f, (unsigned)1.0f, 1.0f);
```

If you're trying to obtain the binary representations, try something like this:

```
float a = 1.0f;
printf(" %x, %u, %f\n", *((unsigned*)&a), *((unsigned*)&a), a);
```

Comment: Perfect. The second's exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: For the reason WHY this thing happens, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941095/convert-ieee-754-float-to-hex-with-c-printf

Comment: `float` being passed as `double` has nothing to do with the ABI. It's part of the standard. Variadic function arguments are always subject to default promotions, so it's impossible to pass `float`, `char`, `short`, or `_Bool` (or any signed/unsigned variants thereof) as a variadic argument.

Answer (score 3):

You tell printf what arguments to expect via the first parameter: the **format string**. The additional values you pass to printf **must match** the format string. If they don't you get garbage output. In your examples, you are passing a floating point vale `1.0f` and you're telling printf to treat it as an integer with `%u` format specifier. You thus get garbage output.

The [man page for printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) has all of the details you need to create the correct format string for the values you want to print.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Every format-field expects exactly the same type as specified by the format-specifier.

On x86 systems, arguments are often passed on the stack, and using an incorrect format-specifier will cause the variable-argument functionality to take the wrong number of bytes from the stack.

In your case, you call printf with 3 floating point values, but floating point values are promoted to double (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion_in_C-like_languages).
So in this case (on x86 systems), there will be 3 times 8 bytes on the stack.

The first format-field will take the number of bytes it expects on the stack:

- %x will take 4 bytes
- %u will also take 4 bytes
- %f will take 8 bytes

So the order of the format-fields will have an influence on the actual data that is printed.  (with %f it is even possible that the floating-point value is an invalid one, which may cause a crash).

If you want to know more about variable argument lists, look at the answers in [Passing of variable arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505344/passing-of-variable-arguments-in-c)

Comment: This answer is rather misleading. There's no reason to even expect that the arguments get passed on the stack; for example, on x86_64, they'll all be in registers, and floating point types will never be misinterpreted as integer types or vice versa (instead they'll be invisible).

Answer (score 1):

When I compile this with gcc I get the following warnings:

```
crazy.c: In function ‘main’:
crazy.c:4: warning: format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’
crazy.c:4: warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘double’
crazy.c:5: warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
crazy.c:5: warning: format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘double’
crazy.c:6: warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
crazy.c:6: warning: format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’
```

This is why you get the garbage output that you are using.  It's a good idea to compile with the strictest warnings possible so you can get early notice of problems like this.

`%u` and `%x` are format specifiers that expect unsigned integers.  You should be using the `%f` floating point specifiers for all of the examples.  This would always give consistent results given floating point numbers.

Comment: Why not add those flags to your answer for a more complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with argument list do not match format descriptors. If you want to print 1.0f as integer value, convert it to integer first:

```
printf("%x, %u, %f,\n", (int)1.0f, (int)1.0f, 1.0f);
```